# How to add an additional check to JWT token lifetime validation?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, bearer-token

In my web application I want to perform all the default lifetime checks (not before, expires, ...), plus perform one additional check (lifetime < 2 hours).

First I tried this:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o => {
        o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            LifetimeValidator = (DateTime? notBefore, DateTime? expires, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) => {
                // --> my custom check <--
            }
        };
    });
```

This will perform my custom check, but it will skip the default implementation, so all the regular checks (not before, expires, ...) are no longer performed.

Then I call the default implementation from within my handler, like this:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o => {
        o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            LifetimeValidator = (DateTime? notBefore, DateTime? expires, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) => {
                    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateLifetime(notBefore, expires, securityToken, validationParameters);
                // --> my custom check <--
            }
        };
    });
```

But this will recursively call my handler and eventually crash my application.

So... what's the correct way to *extend* the default lifetime validator?

Comment: I think you could make a copy of the TokenValidationParameters and pass in an instance with the lifetime validator set to null. Then it won't recursively call your function.

Comment: That did the trick! The TokenValidationParameters class even has a Clone method which makes this really easy! Feel free to write this up as an answer, and I'll upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o => {
        o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            LifetimeValidator = (DateTime? notBefore, DateTime? expires, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) => {
                var clonedParameters = validationParameters.Clone();
                clonedParameters.LifetimeValidator = null;
                bool valid = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateLifetime(notBefore, expires, securityToken, clonedParameters);
                // --> my custom check <--
            }
        };
    });
```

So we copy the `TokenValidationParameters` and set the lifetime validator reference to null so it prevents the recursive call and doesn't modify the actual instance where you registered the validator.

Comment: Hmm, the latest `Validators.ValidateLifetime` signature returns void; it throws exceptions instead when the token fails validation. So we have to catch exceptions now for program flow???

Comment: @xanadont you don't need to catchup, let it thrown. All you need to do is your custom check.